# how to add expand Map and different mode option in mapbox react js

Tags: reactjs, components, mapbox-gl-js

I am using  react map gl to render maps in my react application. But the Maps option seems doesnt provide way to enable features like below

May I know if there is a way to enable this or I need some other tech to do it?

Below is my current map configuration:

```
import ReactMapGL, { FlyToInterpolator, Marker, Popup } from "react-map-gl";

 const mapStyle = {
        height: '100vh',
        width: '60vw',
        zoom: 15
    }
```

Here is some examples concerning with the features I am talking about.

1. Expanding the map
2. Changing map mode. Some may even have the location detection and different style.

How can I provide such option and have a different style?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mapbox with DeckGL to expand the map capabilities -

For example:

```
import { DeckGL } from "@deck.gl/react"
import { StaticMap, FullscreenControl } from "react-map-gl"

   <DeckGL
    width={width}
    height={height}
    controller={true}
    layers={layers}
    initialViewState={{ ...viewport, ... }}
  >
    <StaticMap
      width="100%"
      height="100%"
      attributionControl={false}
      mapStyle={getMapStyle(mapStyle)}
      mapboxApiAccessToken={mapToken}
    >
    <FullscreenControl className={classes.fullScreeenButoon}/> // adding full screen
    </StaticMap>
    {getMapStyleButton()}
  </DeckGL>

const getMapStyle = (mapStyle) = {
   mapStyle === "street" ? "mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10" : "mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-v9"
}

const getMapStyleButton = (mapStyle) => {
   if (mapStyle === "street") {
      return (<Button>...</Button>)
   }
   ...
}
```

for more information: [Deck.gl](https://deck.gl/)

and [react-map-gl](https://visgl.github.io/react-map-gl/) version: 6.1.0

for more react-map-gl/examples/controls: [controls](https://visgl.github.io/react-map-gl/examples/controls)

Comment: Thanks for you answer, could you guide where deck.gl could handle my mentioned features, which are expanding the map and switching mode option.

Comment: i see you used StaticMap, But I am using ReactMapGL; Would there be a impact to my original code ?

Comment: I posted the option how to add buttons to change style only, soon I will add another example for the full-screen button